# How to get access to the other drives in a dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I have a dual boot system (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) in my computer. I want to access the drive (which is available in Windows) in Ubuntu platform. How to do this. Please suggest a way.

Comment: You can just access it. If you get an error than you hibernated Windows .. in this case it is locked. You have to completely shutdown windows first.

Comment: @derHugo how can we just access it?

Comment: Well I'm assuming the OP uses Ubuntu with a GUi and usually all devices mounted or not are visible. To access a drive you just click it. If this throws an error usually the reason is as mentioned a hibernated Windows holding a lock on it

Answer (score 0):

If it has not been mounted automatically it has to be mounted.

`mount` will show the mounted partitions.

`sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` and `sudo parted -l /dev/sda`
will show what partitions exist